# Drupal 8: How to get the URL and title of a specific page in twig

Tags: url, twig, drupal-8

I have a template file called "page.html.twig".
Now I want to set a link to a specific page / node. How do I do that? In the Drupal 8 documentation i found `<a href="{{ url('view.frontpage.page_1') }}">{{ 'View all content'|t }}</a>`
but now I don't know how to set this up right.

Let's say I have a page called "Page" and the URL is "example.com/page" (both set in Content->edit). How must it look like? `<a href="{{ url('view.Page') }}">{{ 'Page'|t }}</a>` doesn't work.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a good explanation on how to create links in twig templates in Drupal 8.
https://chromatichq.com/blog/creating-links-within-twig-templates-using-path-and-url
https://wrightshq.com/understanding-twig-in-drupal-8/

Your example code would be for a view url.
In case you want to reference a specific page/node you can do the following. The path() method would generate a relative url where url() would produce an absolute url. page_nid would be the nid of the node.

```
   {% set page_nid = 60 %}

   <a href="{{ path('entity.node.canonical', {'node': page_nid}) }}">{{ Page|t }}</a>
```